# Save as webpage after updating R markdown doesn't work

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, rstudio, installation-package

I want to save a plotly graph as webpage in HTML. But then I get this message.

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ETbb.png]

I click yes and let R install this package. After 46 seconds, I get the message that the installation has succeeded, however I see a lot of red warning messages. These are the last few lines:

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpysVdFP\downloaded_packages'


<U+2714> Package 'rmarkdown' successfully installed.
Warning messages:
1: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\***\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\00LOCK\htmltools\libs\x64\htmltools.dll to C:\Users\***\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\htmltools\libs\x64\htmltools.dll: Permission denied
2: In utils::install.packages("bslib", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package 'bslib' had non-zero exit status
3: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\***\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\00LOCK\htmltools\libs\x64\htmltools.dll to C:\Users\***\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\htmltools\libs\x64\htmltools.dll: Permission denied
4: In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'htmltools' had non-zero exit status
5: In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'xfun' had non-zero exit status
6: In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'bslib' had non-zero exit status
7: In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'rmarkdown' had non-zero exit status
```

For example I can't find the folder (RtmpysVdFP) where the source packages are supposed to be in.

If I want to save the plot again as a webpage, it gives me again the message to install r markdown package.

How can I solve this?

Comment: ```Permission denied``` Do you work not on your PC?

Comment: How do you mean? Of course I work on my PC.

Comment: F.e. ```In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\***\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\00LOCK\htmltools\libs\x64\htmltools.dll to C:\Users\***\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\htmltools\libs\x64\htmltools.dll: Permission denied``` I wanted to say, that maybe your PC is connected to the company network with any group policy.

Comment: Did you have multiple copies of R running? Try restarting your machine and then try installing the package again.